# How to load the environment dependant on domain-name?

Tags: symfony

We recently buid a project basing on a self written frontend framework were the domain name was  used to determine the current environment.
The code looked about like this:

```
switch($domain){
    case 'site.local':
         $env = "dev";
         break;
    case 'test.site.de':
         $env = 'test';
         break;
    case 'site.de':
         $env = 'prod';
}
```

My question is: How can this be done in Symfony?
Is it enough to just load the AppKernel-instace dependant on the domain like this? :

```
switch($domain){
    case 'site.local':
         $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
         break;
    case 'test.site.de':
         $kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);
         break;
    case 'site.de':
         $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to find the domain name. After that it's pretty much straightforward. Although, I am unsure about `case default` syntax validity.

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
switch($domain){
    case 'site.local':
    case default:
         $env = "dev";
         break;
    case 'test.site.de':
         $env = 'test';
         break;
    case 'site.de':
         $env = 'prod';
}
```

---

## ! Beware !

Make sure you protect your `dev`/`test` environment by using IP filter and/or authentication. `dev` can leak a lot of very sensitive information to your attacker and could easily lead to your app being compromised.

---

Comment: Ty for the hint. I removed the default-case now entirely.