# Symfony 3: load different parameters file depending from subdomain

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to load a different parameters file depending on the domain or subdomain? Without changing core Symfony files.

I need this in order to load template files and styles for different subdomains.

Comment: Do you need to setup different config for each (sub)domain manually or want to have some kind of dynamic config?

Comment: Are you able to configure web-server?

Comment: @dragoste  I want to have one code deployed to one folder, the only change is in the sub-domain.
Dimitry: Yes I'm able to config the server.

Comment: I would suggest to use separate Symfony's environments,which would let you provide separate configs for each (extending the base one). You can define environment basing on (sub)domain in `app.php`. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875603/how-to-load-the-environment-dependant-on-domain-name

Comment: Check out theming bundles like LiipThemeBundle.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318711/how-to-configure-symfony2-3-to-handle-different-domains-serving-different-views/39326260#39326260